# GPG (xubuntu) - old password works instead of new one

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent

6 months ago I changed my GPG keys password. In shell it seems to work alright. But encrypted file can be decrypted in two ways:

- with command in terminal`gpg file.txt.asc` - new password works. Old one does not. (which is correct)
- in bash script run via terminal `sh /absolute/path/script.sh` I insert `#!/bin/bash` with a line `gpg file.txt.asc` - **new password isn't working. Only the old one works.**

So I cannot decrypt files with scripts.

---

- `.gnupg` folder has been moved to encrypted location and it is symlinked back to original location
- I tried to change password with `gpg --edit-key` as well as `gpg2 --edit-key` (both work the same)
- gpg cache has been wiped off, I also tried to delete keys and import them back again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out afterall:

- There were different secret keys in gpg and gpg2
- I had an alias `alias gpg="gpg2"`
- Script was working with "gpg" while shell worked with gpg2 (even when I thought the otherwise)